# redirecting to a variable href from python

Tags: python, html

I'm writing a wiki for a Udacity assignment and want to create an "Edit" button in the navbar.  Basically the functionality I'm looking for is when you hit Edit you are redirected to an edit page with the current content displayed in the edit box.  When you save that page the content is updated on the original page.

I believe my problem is in the html which is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        {% if not user %}
        <a href="/signup">Signup</a>|<a href="/login">Login</a>
        {% else %}
        <a href="/_edit{{wiki_url}}">Edit</a>|<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
```

The relevant python code is:

```
class WikiPage(Handler):
    def get(self, wiki_url):
        page = None
        ver = self.request.get("v")
        user = self.user
        print("***** WikiPage(Handler) wiki_url = %s, ver = %r, user = %s" % (wiki_url, ver, user))
        if ver:
            ver = int(ver)
            page = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Wiki WHERE url = :url AND version = :ver ORDER BY created DESC", url=wiki_url, ver=ver).get()
            if not page:
                self.redirect("%s" % wiki_url)
        else:
            page = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Wiki WHERE url = :url ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1", url = wiki_url).get()
            print("*** No versions *** wiki_url=%s page = %r" % (wiki_url, page))
            if not page:
                self.redirect("/_edit%s" % wiki_url)

        if page:
            id = page.key().id()
            thisPage = Wiki.get_by_id(int(id))
            print("*** WikiPage(Handler) *** wiki_url = %s page = %r" % (wiki_url, page))
            if user:
                self.render('show_page.html', content=thisPage.content, url=wiki_url)
            else:
                self.redirect("/login")
```

What's happening now is I get redirected to /_edit/_edit regardless of which page I'm trying to edit.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Adding the EditPage handler class:

```
class EditPage(Handler):
def render_editwiki(self, user="", title="", content="", error=""):
    self.render("edit_page.html", user=user, title=title, content=content, error=error)

def get(self, wiki_url):
    v = self.request.get('v')
    user = self.user

    if user:
        if v:
            v = int(v)
            thisWiki = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Wiki WHERE url = :url AND version = :ver ORDER BY created DESC", url=wiki_rul, ver=v).get()
            if not thisWiki:
                self.redirect("/wiki/_edit%s" % wiki_url)
        else:
            thisWiki = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Wiki WHERE url = :url ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1", url=wiki_url).get()
            if not thisWiki:
                self.render_editwiki(user, wiki_url)

        if thisWiki:
            id = thisWiki.key().id()
            w = Wiki.get_by_id(int(id))
            self.render_editwiki(user, w.url, w.content)
    else:
        self.redirect("/wiki/signup")

def post(self, wiki_url):
    content = self.request.get("content")
    user = self.user

    if user:
        if content:
            thisWiki = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Wiki where url = :url ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1", url=wiki_url).get()
            if thisWiki:
                id = thisWiki.key().id()
                previous = Wiki.get_by_id(int(id))
                current = previous.version + 1
                w = Wiki(url=wiki_url, content=content, version=current)
                w.put()
            else:
                w = Wiki(url=wiki_url, content=content,version=1)
                w.put()
            self.redirect('%s' % str(wiki_url))
        else:
            error = "No Content"
            self.render("edit_page.html", content=content, error=error)
    else:
        self.redirect("/wiki/signup")
```

Comment: You should mention in the tags or body of question what libraries/frameworks you're using -- flask?

Comment: ahhh it's google app engine so I'm using Jinja2

Answer (score 0):

Have you already written a url case for the edit urls? It seems like you are being redirected to `/_edit/_edit` because `wiki_url` is `/_edit`. I'm guessing this is what's happening:

- you visit a regular page (`wiki_url = ?`)
- you click the edit url
- you visit the edit url, but there is no page (`wiki_url = '/_edit'`)
- you are redirected to the edit url (of the edit page), which is `/_edit/_edit`.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense, but it only goes to /_edit/_edit if wiki_url = "".  My debug print statements actually show a value though, for example /wiki_test.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But your saying it redirects you to `/_edit/_edit` no matter what the initial `wiki_url` was?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  I've been fighting this for quite a while.  If I manually type /_edit/wiki_test it works perfectly and redirects back to /wiki_test after I save the changes.  If I hit the Edit button on /wiki_test it redirects to /_edit/_edit.